# radclient: Failed to find IP addres for host User-Name = Success

Tags: ubuntu, radius, freeradius

I am trying to send a request with radclient (http://wiki.freeradius.org/config/Radclient) to an actual radius Server. 
So I am sending this Request from my Ubuntu Servers Terminal

`radclient User-Name = myusername@domain.com User-Password = myPassword Radserver auth Secret`

And everytime i tried it I got this message:

```
radclient: Failed to find IP addres for host User-Name = Success
```

What does it mean? Does this mean that he isn't finding the radius Server? And if so why is it saying User-Name = Success?

EDIT:

So this is now the Request I send and which seem to work.

```
echo "User-Name = user@domain.com, User-Password = myPassword" | radclient Radserver auth SECRET -x
```

The User-Name and the User-Password are correct and should be accepted, but they aren't.

```
Sending Access-⁠Request of id 99 to RadServerIP port 1812
User-⁠Name = "user"
User-⁠Password = "myPassword"
rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host RadServerIP port 1812, id=99, length=20
```

What can be the cause of that Access-Reject? Because the Username and the Password are definetely correct.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the arguments in the wrong way.

Attribute lists need to be read from stdin, or files specified with -f.

For your example, the correct invocation would be:

```
echo "User-Name = myusername@domain.com User-Password = myPassword" | radclient Radserver auth Secret
```

Comment: Thanks, my Request seems now to work, but i don't get the result which I expect and want. Maybe u can help me with that aswell

Comment: No, you need to mark this question as resolved and ask a new question.